# MongoDB how to find documents with undefined $lookups (aggregation)

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregate

I have a document in an origin collection that holds OR not holds a reference to a foreign collection document - The key is not mandatory, so sometimes it's missing.

In such a situation the $lookup is "failed" and the desired document is not getting fetched from the DB.

This is the pipeline:

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "tables",
      let: { "enginefuel_type": "$engine.fuel_type" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$enginefuel_type"] }}},
        { $project: { title: 1 }}
      ],
      as: "engine.fuel_type"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$engine.fuel_type"
  },

  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tables",
      let: { "enginegear": "$engine.gear" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$enginegear"] }}},
        { $project: { title: 1 }}
      ],
      as: "engine.gear"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$engine.gear"
  }
```

I need the document to be found anyway - whether it has the **engine.fuel_type** and/or **engine.gear** fields or not.
If there is, so it should take the document from the foreign, otherwise just remain empty but not ignore the whole document.

I thought about making some pre-if statement checking if the field exists before making the aggregate query (could also be more efficient, reducing requests to the DB).

Is there any good way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lookup stage works as you need it to, even though the field is not present in the origin collection, the document will not be ignored and will be a part of the result with "engine.fuel_type" array containing 0 elements.

It's the unwind stage that removes the documents which have 0 array elements. Fortunately, [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage provides preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:  option, that includes all the result.
So you could try to do something like this:-

```
$lookup: {
      from: "tables",
      let: { "enginefuel_type": "$engine.fuel_type" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$enginefuel_type"] }}},
        { $project: { title: 1 }}
      ],
      as: "engine.fuel_type"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "engine.fuel_type",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  }
```